# how to revert back to 12.0 network manager

Tags: networking

I recently did an automatic update from 12.04 to 14.0. everything
seemed to work very well until I rebooted. Now the network doesn't work.
The new plasma network manager either doesn't save the network settings
at reboot or it goes to a default setting. In either case it doesn't work
and I cannot even set it up manually. I had no problem at all with the older
version, it was very user friendly and usually set up automatically. Why doesn't this one. 
     Is there any way, without the use of the Internet, can I change the network manager back to the version that came with 12.04 and keep the new version 14.0 Kubuntu. At least it works.
Now I am without network and Internet in my shop.

Comment: How are you using the network connection? Connecting to a WiFi-"router"? Automatic IP addresses (DHCP) or static?

Comment: I am using eth0 going into a wireless router setup as a client which worked perfectly with the network manager under 12.04. This version is much more user friendly than that of the new plasma version. This is why I would like to delete the new version and replace with the older version.

Comment: I am using eth0 going into a wireless router set up as client which worked

Comment: If this is a stay-at-home computer, I suggest removing NM altogether and setting up /etc/network/interfaces permanently. Are you sure this is not a driver problem? What settings are you unable to save?

Comment: Would you recommend removing the Network manager via the package manager? Next where can I find the setup (I am assuming this is a command line setup) in detail?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a stay at home computer, it may be preferable to remove Network Manager altogether and simply set up manual methods. First, be very certain that the driver and hardware seem to be working as expected. Check:

```
ifconfig
```

Do you see an eth0 interface? Does it respond as expected if you do:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Because NM is trying to control networking, this command will probably not actually acquire an IP address; the hope is that it will produce no errors. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add several lines to the file so that it reads as follows:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.1.100  
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Of course, substitute your details here. Now do:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

It might take a reboot.

Once you are satisfied, you may remove Network Manager in Software Center.

Comment: This seems to work OK, however I would prefer static addressing since I am using Filezilla to transfer and backup files.  I can still live with this by changing my addresses in Filezilla. If there is an easy way to change the addressing to static I would appreciate it.  Thanks and God bless.

Comment: Please see my edit above.